# Why is this pattern needed?

Tags: javascript

Looking at the code of ryanve's [response.js](https://github.com/ryanve/response.js/blob/master/response.js#L7), it begins with the following:

```
(function(root, name, make) {
  var $ = root['jQuery'] || root['Zepto'] || root['ender'] || root['elo'];
  if (typeof module != 'undefined' && module['exports']) module['exports'] = make($);
  else root[name] = make($);
}(this, 'Response', function($) {
...
```

What is this called, why is it useful and what does it do exactly?

Comment: I never heard of response.js but it seems to check for four supported libraries (jQuery, Zepto, ender and elo) and then attach itself to that library or export a module if CommonJS is used. It'S useful as it tries to minimize its global footprint while adapting to environment it's supposed to run in.

Comment: Does that mean it can be loaded using RequireJS or Browserify? Is it for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
(function(root, name, make){...})(this,'Response', function($){...});
```

calls "init" function passing default namespace (`this` is `window` in browsers) reference as the `root` variable.

This:

```
var $ = root['jQuery'] || root['Zepto'] || root['ender'] || root['elo'];
```

gets reference of either jQuery or Zepto, etc. ... module.

And this:

```
if (typeof module != 'undefined' && module['exports']) 
  module['exports'] = make($);
else 
  root[name] = make($);
```

checks if file is loaded with module object (most probably CommonJS environment) available and calls "constructor" `make()` and registers its exhaust as a module.
Otherwise registers make() result as an object in global namespace ( `root[name] = ...` )

Comment: Does this mean this library can be loaded either as a jQuery|Zepto|ender|elo plugin, and also as a module on Node.js, or using RequireJS or Browserify?

Comment: @AlainJacometForte Yes

Comment: @AlainJacometForte it means a) the library knows about/requires? either one of jQuery|Zepto|ender|elo and b) if `module` variable is available (e.g. as http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_object ) it will be registered as a module there. 
For exact usage you should use its documentation I think.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of hook. This is exactly you can add current plugin name "Response" with any of mentioned library like `"jQuery, Zepto, ender, elo"`. And again "Response" leave anchor point
in following code.

```
if (typeof module != 'undefined' && module['exports']) module['exports'] = make($);
else root[name] = make($);
```

And code it self need some changes. Let us take jQuery, here `"this"` refers `window`, based on the code the author trying to like `window.jQuery.Response = function(jQuery){}` and module in "if" condition is a global. It will be available when you are working NodeJs like environment. In this case, `Response` attached with that global variable, instead of jQuery.

**Note: Simply we can say, "Response" definition can work with any of mention library and/or library which expose "module" global.**

Answer (score 0):

This pattern helps avoid writing code in the global scope, and the function written on the first line of your code is a self invoking function. A self invoking function is invoked as soon as it is declared. Here is how to do it.

```
(function(argument1, argument2, argument2){
    alert("Self invoked");
})(arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

in your case the first argument is `this` which refers to the `window` object, second is a string and third is a callback.